# Google Apps Script, HTML addClickHandler ServerHandler does NOT work

Tags: google-apps-script

Can anyone confirm that HTML widgets accept ClickHandlers on the Server side ? I can't get my below code to work.

I create a serverHandler (and for good measure I have even added a useless callback element). Subsequently, I add it to a HTML.addClickHander (for good measure I have even added it to .addMouseUpHandler as well). The function is NOT executed.

```
var mouseclick = app.createServerHandler("handleTrainingClick_").addCallbackElement(lstFilter);
var params = [ "fromOrg", "trainingTitle", "dueDate", "medical", "status" ];
var resultSet = blSelectActiveTrainings_();
while (resultSet.hasNext()) {
    var training = resultSet.next();
    var html = TRAINING_ROW;
    for (var pI in params) {
        html = html.replace("$"+params[pI], training[params[pI]]); 
    }
     pnlList.add(app.createHTML(html).setId(training.id).addClickHandler(mouseclick).addMouseUpHandler(mouseclick)
                   .addMouseMoveHandler(mousemove).addMouseOutHandler(mouseout).addMouseOverHandler(mouseover));
```

}

```
function handleTrainingClick_(e) {
    Logger.log(e.source);
    var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
    return app;
}
```

Comment: Try to remove the `_` in the end of the handler name, i.e. `handleTrainingClick` instead of `handleTrainingClick_`

Comment: megabyte1024 : tried without the underscore - still does NOT work.

Comment: Can you create and publish a small example by using the `Deploy Web App` GAS feature and post a source link to this published project here? It will help to understand what is the problem.

Comment: My mistake, it was incorrect reference in my code. Server side HTML handlers work just fine. Appreciate your efforts.

Comment: Request: Please put the "it was incorrect reference in my code" in the answer box.  (ie you answered your own question).

Answer (score 0):

HTML widgets server side handlers work just fine. It was an incorrect reference in my code. Thanks all.